# Routing in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have  a problem in my cakephp project.I have used css and js in layout using Html helper eg.

```
 echo $this->Html->css(array('custom/style'));
echo $this->Html->script(array('custom/jquery-1.7.1.min'));
```

Css and js not working in my project and redirect function like

```
$this->Html->link('test',array('controller' => 'pages','action' => 'index'))
```

and its looks like this :- www.example.com/app/webroot/pages/index.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to  enable mod_rewrite on your server